# SQL Server wrong result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I used select on 2 different tables, return value is has to be same but is not, I can't figure it out so we are here

```
update oper
set OdenecekTutar = 
      (select 
          case 
             when round(sum(rezervasyon.odeme_satis_kalan), 2) is not null
                then round(sum(rezervasyon.odeme_satis_kalan), 2) 
                else 0 
          end
      from rezervasyon 
      where rezervasyon.oper = oper.operID)

    select round(sum(oper.OdenecekTutar),2)  as borc_from_oper from oper
//borc_from_oper => 1372283,38

    select round(sum(odeme_satis_kalan),2) as borc_from_oper2 from rezervasyon
//borc_from_oper2 => 1372283,35
```

relationship in 2 table;

oper.operID one rezervasyon.oper is many,

`oper.total/\*total` price of all rezervasyons price this case this column `'OdenecekTutar'\*/`

`sum(rezervasyon.price/\*this case this column is 'odeme_satis_kalan'\*/)`

So what is wrong in my code?

Comment: 1. what are u trying to achieve with case statement 
2. where is JOIN 
3. sample inputs & result
4. error code

Comment: i have 2 different table and 2 different case 1 case is save my total price other one all selled service detail but i can't get same result with same data

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is the result the same if you don't use the round function? If so just don't round in your update statement.

Also you could change your case statement to:

```
round(sum(ISNULL(rezervasyon.odeme_satis_kalan, 0)),2)
```

Comment: My code is just a compact form of your case statement... But you should try not to round in your update

Answer (score 0):

The difference is simply because the updated values in [oper] are rounded.

But those in [rezervasyon] aren't rounded.
While that last query does a SUM over all records.
Not over the grouped rounded totals.

Below is an example snippet to demonstrate that effect:

```
declare @oper table (operID int primary key, OdenecekTutar decimal(10,2));
insert into @oper (operID) values (1),(2),(3);

declare @rezervasyon table (rezervasyonID int identity(1,1) primary key, oper int, odeme_satis_kalan decimal(10,4));
insert into @rezervasyon (oper, odeme_satis_kalan) values (1,10.018),(1,20.028),(2,30.018),(2,40.028);

select * from @rezervasyon;

update o
set OdenecekTutar = coalesce(round(r.sum_odeme_satis_kalan, 2) ,0)
from @oper as o
left join (select oper, sum(odeme_satis_kalan) as sum_odeme_satis_kalan from @rezervasyon group by oper) as r 
  on (r.oper = o.operID);

select * from @oper;

select round(sum(OdenecekTutar),2) as round_sum_OdenecekTutar from @oper;
-- Result: round_sum_OdenecekTutar = 100.10

select round(sum(odeme_satis_kalan),2) as round_sum_odeme_satis_kalan, sum(odeme_satis_kalan) as sum_odeme_satis_kalan from @rezervasyon;
-- Result: round_sum_odeme_satis_kalan = 100.0900

--
-- Group first, then sum
--
select sum(round_sum_odeme_satis_kalan) as total_round_sum_odeme_satis_kalan from (select oper, round(sum(odeme_satis_kalan),2) as round_sum_odeme_satis_kalan from @rezervasyon group by oper) q;
--Result: total_round_sum_odeme_satis_kalan = 100.1000
```

Personally, I wouldn't round it in the update and use a type for [OdenecekTutar] that has sufficient precision.
But I'm guessing that it's required because the type of [OdenecekTutar] is a decimal(N,2)

Also, the results would still be different if there are records in [rezervasyon] where the operId doesn't match with [oper].